# Is there a word that describes the act of trying to impose guilt on another party?

Tags: single-word-requests

Context: an organization with which I am affiliated just sent an e-mail asking for donations. It was an obvious attempt to make everyone feel guilty about not donating. I wanted to send a message to a colleague: "this email is dripping with <*enter word here*>" -- but  I couldn't come up with a word.

I know the of the phrase "*guilt trip*", which describes the actual guilt imposition, but it doesn't quite fit the usage I was after. Is there a word that describes the *act* of trying to impose guilt, that would fit the usage above?

Comment: It's not a single word, but "guilt induction" seems to be used quite a lot, and it fits perfectly in the example sentence.

Comment: How about the simple *blame*? http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/blame

Comment: Why doesn't "guilt tripping" work? It seems to describe the situation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I was young we used to talk informally about 'guilt-tripping'. It's in Cambridge –

guilt-trip
verb [ T ]   informal

to make someone feel guilty, usually in order to make them do something:

*He's just trying to guilt-trip you into paying him more.*

[Guilt-trip (Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/guilt-trip)

Comment: *X-trip* compounds almost seem to be one of two sorts: the one physical, the other mental. So *adventure trip, camping trip, round trip, return trip* are one thing, but *power trip, ego trip, head trip, guilt trip, mind trip* are another—which, being mental, are perhaps more aligned with an *acid trip* or a *bad trip* than with a physical *road trip* or a *pack trip*.

Comment: @tchrist I tend to agree with you about 'guilt trip' bring related to post-WW2 drug culture. I can't remember its being used before about 1970 personally.

Comment: @BoldBen - yes, and people used to **lay** guilt-trips **on** others. Still do, apparently. I see this exact usage listed in Macmillan and used in 2014 in Psychology Today - 'laying a guilt trip is a stealth way of venting buried anger. '

Answer (score 7):

**shaming**

> **shame** TRANSITIVE VERB
> (of a person, action, or situation) make (someone) feel ashamed.
> *‘I tried to shame him into giving some away’*
> [LEXICO](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/shame)